# Macro involving TikZ mode does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I've create a macro for labelling fragments of sentences. It's designed to replace a segment of text with a label. Unfortunately, it fails to compile whenever the text fragment contains a non-alphanumeric character;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\LabelText}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(LabelText.base)]
    \node [
      text width=width("#1"),
      text centered,
      draw=none,
      thick,
      rectangle,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      fill={#3},
    ] (LabelText) {#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\padv}[1]{\LabelText{#1}{\strut Adv}{blue!30}}%

\begin{document}
  This is an \padv{adverb,}
\end{document}
```

The macro will work if the comma is removed from \padv{}. I would like it to work with non-alpha-numeric characters. Any help greatly appreciated.

NB it is supposed to look like this...

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `\newcommand{\padv}[1]{\LabelText{{#1}}{\strut Adv}{blue!30}}%` depending on how you want the comma to be treated.

Comment: Brill. That works, and so simple... If you add it as an answer I'll vote for it.

Comment: Alternately, you could leave `\padv` as you had, and modify the `\Labeltext` line `text width=width("{#1}"),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways to deal with it.

One is to modify the `\LabelText` macro to embrace the use of `#1` as in

```
\newcommand{\LabelText}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(LabelText.base)]
    \node [
      text width=width("{#1}"),
      text centered,
      draw=none,
      thick,
      rectangle,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      fill={#3},
    ] (LabelText) {#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

The other is to double embrace `#1` in the `\padv` definition:

```
\newcommand{\padv}[1]{\LabelText{{#1}}{\strut Adv}{blue!30}}%
```

Either way will keep the contents of the `#1` argument in its own group.